# How to persist data between xcode builds?

Tags: ios, local-storage, storage

I'm actually developping an iOS Application and I'm facing a problem. In my application I have to store two kind of data : a product catalog, and a user preferences list on these products.

The catalog is a sqlite database and I need to update my catalog product at every build on xcode. No problem for this one I've added the file in the "Copy Bundle Resources" of the "Build Phases" of my project. So every time I build my application on xcode, the iPhone gets an updated database.

**My problem is :** I'd also like to store user preferences on these products that **have to** persist between xcode builds.

Question :

- Is it possible to do something like this?

If yes : How? Is it possible to store this data in a sqlite database? What kind of file architecture am I supposed to implement to do something like this?

I've actually made a lot of research on this subject, but I can't find a solution...

Correct me if I'm doing it wrong, but I think this is possible.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. The thing is, I think it is possible to realize something like I described before but I don't know how to do it. I'm still interested in the solution if someone have it.

The solution is to decentralize databases by using **Firebase**. By using Firebase database solution I can persist data through xcode builds.